# Making a wheel of fortune game, how do I print out the name of the person who guessed the phrase?

Tags: java, arraylist

EDIT - The game now ends when the player correctly enters a phrase, need a break in my for loop. However, when printing who wins, it prints the last name in the arraylist, when I want it to print who correctly guessed the phrase.

So far, everything else works in my code, such as it listing the amount of players one entered into an array list, lists their earnings after the round ends, etc. But what I am now trying to do is list the name of the person who guessed the phrase. Whenever I try to print the name of the person who guessed it, it prints the next players name instead, not the person who got the phrase. I'm going to post two parts of the code where I think the error could be located.

The first is where the stats are displayed, the second block is where the players keep guessing until the phrase is reached, and the third block is the getname and getwinnings methods However, the game continues and lets other players get one more guess. I want it to print out whoever got the phrase correct first.

Lastly the final block is the entire code for the game class, not the entire program, but the code where the error is occurring (error as in not printing out who won)

This could also be fixed if the puzzle ends once the phrase is guessed, which should happen when !puzzleSolved is called in the second block, but it continues for some reason until all players finish guessing.

```
 if (guess.compareToIgnoreCase(phrase) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed it!");
        System.out.println("Now pass it to the next person, they get one chance to guess the phrase!");
        puzzleSolved = true;
        // Round is over.
        System.out.println("The player who won is " +players.getName());
        System.out.println("Everyone's earnings are ");
        for (Player earnings : Players){
            System.out.println(earnings.getName());
            System.out.println("$" +earnings.getWinnings());
        }

public void playGame() throws InterruptedException {
    // while the puzzle isn't solved, keep going
    while (!puzzleSolved) {
        // let the players take turns guessing
        int guess = 0;
        for (Player turn : Players) { // Enhanced (for each) look to cycle through players
            Players.get(guess);
            guess++;
            playTurn(turn);
        }
    }
}

public int getWinnings() {
    return winnings;
}

/**
 * Adds amount to the player's winnings
 * @param amount int money to add
 */
public void incrementScore(int amount) {
    if (amount < 0) return;
    this.winnings += amount;
}

/**
 * Getter 
 * @return String player's name 
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public WofFortuneGame(Wheel wheel) throws InterruptedException {
    // get the wheel
    this.wheel = wheel;

    // do all the initialization for the game
    setUpGame();

}

/**
 * Plays the game
 *
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void playGame() throws InterruptedException {
    // while the puzzle isn't solved, keep going
    while (!puzzleSolved) {
        // let the players take turns guessing
        int guess = 0;
        for (Player turn : Players) { // Enhanced (for each) look to cycle through players
            Players.get(guess);
            guess++;
            playTurn(turn);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets up all necessary information to run the game
 */
private void setUpGame() {
    addPhrase(); // Calling method to add more phrases to the game

    // create a single player 
    player1 = new Player("Player1");

    // ask how many people are going to play
    System.out.println("How many players will be participating today?");
    Scanner playerCount = new Scanner(System.in);
    int player = playerCount.nextInt();
    System.out.print(+player);
    if (player == 0) {
        System.out.println(" You can't play a game with 0 players!"); // "Easter Egg"
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println(" players will be playing, please enter their names"); // ask for players names
    for (int i = 0; i < player; i++) {
        Scanner playerName = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = playerName.nextLine();

        players = new Player(name);
        Players.add(players);
    } // add players to Players array list
    // print out the rules
    System.out.println("RULES!");
    System.out.println("Each player gets to spin the wheel, to get a number value");
    System.out.println("Each player then gets to guess a letter. If that letter is in the phrase, ");
    System.out.println(" the player will get the amount from the wheel for each occurence of the letter");
    System.out.println("If you have found a letter, you will also get a chance to guess at the phrase");
    System.out.println("Each player only has three guesses, once you have used up your three guesses, ");
    System.out.println("you can still guess letters, but no longer solve the puzzle.");
    System.out.println();
    // User can enter own phrase
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter your own phrase? (Y/N)");
    Scanner customPhrase = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner for if yes or no to create custom phrase
    char letter = customPhrase.next().charAt(0);
    if ((letter == 'Y') || (letter == 'y')) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your phrase!");
        Scanner typePhrase = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner to type custom phrase
        String custom = typePhrase.nextLine();
        phrase = custom;
        System.out.println("Now let's play!");
    } else {
        Random randomPhrase = new Random();
        phrase = Phrases.get(randomPhrase.nextInt(Phrases.size()));
    }
    // for each character in the phrase, create a letter and add to letters arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        //   letter_array[i] = new Letter(phrase.charAt(i)); stores in standard array
        Letters.add(new Letter(phrase.charAt(i))); // stores in array list
    }
    // setup done
}

/**
 * Method to add a number of phrases to implement into the game. Using
 * ArrayList, one could easily add more phrases if the game becomes boring.
 */
private void addPhrase() {
    String phrase1 = "Where the Sun Dont Shine";
    Phrases.add(phrase1);
    String phrase2 = "High Noon";
    Phrases.add(phrase2);
    String phrase3 = "Fly Me to the Moon";
    Phrases.add(phrase3);
    String phrase4 = "Im Batman";
    Phrases.add(phrase4);
    String phrase5 = "Happy Halloween";
    Phrases.add(phrase5);
    String phrase6 = "Rock and Roll";
    Phrases.add(phrase6);
    String phrase7 = "Stay in School";
    Phrases.add(phrase7);
    String phrase8 = "There is no place like home";
    Phrases.add(phrase8);
    String phrase9 = "Survival of the Fittest";
    Phrases.add(phrase9);
    String phrase10 = "No Mans Sky";
    Phrases.add(phrase10);
    String phrase11 = "Offense is the Best Defense";
    Phrases.add(phrase11);
    String phrase12 = "I Play to Win";
    Phrases.add(phrase12);
}

/**
 * One player's turn in the game Spin wheel, pick a letter, choose to solve
 * puzzle if letter found
 *
 * @param player
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
private void playTurn(Player player) throws InterruptedException {
    int money = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(player.getName() + ", you have $" + player.getWinnings());
    System.out.println("Spin the wheel! <press enter>");
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("<SPINNING>");
    Thread.sleep(200);
    Wheel.WedgeType type = wheel.spin();
    System.out.print("The wheel landed on: ");
    switch (type) {
        case MONEY:
            money = wheel.getAmount();
            System.out.println("$" + money);
            break;

        case LOSE_TURN:
            System.out.println("LOSE A TURN");
            System.out.println("So sorry, you lose a turn.");
            return; // doesn't get to guess letter

        case BANKRUPT:
            System.out.println("BANKRUPT");
            player.bankrupt();
            return; // doesn't get to guess letter

        default:

    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Here is the puzzle:");
    showPuzzle();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(player.getName() + ", please guess a letter.");
    //String guess = sc.next();

    char letter = sc.next().charAt(0);
    if (!Character.isAlphabetic(letter)) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, but only alphabetic characters are allowed. You lose your turn.");
    } else {
        // search for letter to see if it is in
        int numFound = 0;
        for (Letter l : Letters) {
            if ((l.getLetter() == letter) || (l.getLetter() == Character.toUpperCase(letter))) {
                l.setFound();
                numFound += 1;
            }
        }
        if (numFound == 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, but there are no " + letter + "'s.");
        } else {
            if (numFound == 1) {
                System.out.println("Congrats! There is 1 letter " + letter + ":");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Congrats! There are " + numFound + " letter " + letter + "'s:");
            }
            System.out.println();
            showPuzzle();
            System.out.println();
            player.incrementScore(numFound * money);
            System.out.println("You earned $" + (numFound * money) + ", and you now have: $" + player.getWinnings());

            System.out.println("Would you like to try to solve the puzzle? (Y/N)");
            letter = sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println();
            if ((letter == 'Y') || (letter == 'y')) {
                solvePuzzleAttempt(player);
            }
        }

    }

}

/**
 * Logic for when user tries to solve the puzzle
 *
 * @param player
 */
private void solvePuzzleAttempt(Player player) {

    if (player.getNumGuesses() >= 3) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, but you have used up all your guesses.");
        return;
    }

    player.incrementNumGuesses();
    System.out.println("What is your solution?");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("\n");
    String guess = sc.next();
    if (guess.compareToIgnoreCase(phrase) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed it!");
        System.out.println("Now pass it to the next person, they get one chance to guess the phrase!");
        puzzleSolved = true;
        // Round is over.
        System.out.println("The player who won is " +players.getName());
        System.out.println("Everyone's earnings are ");
        for (Player earnings : Players){
            System.out.println(earnings.getName());
            System.out.println("$" +earnings.getWinnings());
        }
        // TODO
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, but that is not correct.");
    }
}

/**
 * Display the puzzle on the console
 */
private void showPuzzle() {
    System.out.print("\t\t");
    for (Letter l : Letters) {
        if (l.isSpace()) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        } else if (l.isFound()) {
            System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(l.getLetter()) + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" _ ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

}

/**
 * For a new game reset player's number of guesses to 0
 */
public void reset() {
    players.reset();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your code for `players.getName()` and any other relevant code?

Comment: Added. The players are in an arraylist, and I need to print out the player who last guessed the phrase.

Comment: Can you post all your code for the game.

Comment: Okay, its the last block.

Comment: The issue you appear to be having is that you loop through all the players despite the fact that the puzzle has been solved. You should change the method to make it so that once the puzzle is solved, then the game is over rather than allowing everyone else to keep guessing. You do this by using a typical for loop and getting the player, allowing them to guess, and breaking the loop if the puzzle is solved.

Comment: Okay, now once a player correctly guesses the phrase, it ends the game. However, when printing who wins, it prints the very last player who entered, not the player who won. Heres my output. Gladio won, not ignis... Excuse the funny names ;)                                                                                         What is your solution?
cool
Congratulations! You guessed it!
The player who guessed correctly is ignis
Everyone's earnings are 
gladio
$50
noctis
$0
ignis
$0

Would you like to play again?

Comment: The reason it does that is because you passing the last player who entered into the method that handles that. You need to keep a reference to who won.

Comment: Reference? Such as a variable?

Comment: Couldn't figure it out... Would something like another for loop work?